# hide div if different class value jquery

Tags: jquery

This is the html:

```
 <div class="messages">
  <div class="conflict">
   <div class="alert alert-info">
    Conflict
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="account">
   <div class="alert alert-info">
    Account
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

This is the css:

```
.new_inquiry > form > .messages > .conflict, .account { display: none;}
```

This is the jquery code:

```
$('#inquiry_theme').change(function(){
    if($('#inquiry_theme').val() == 'Conflict with the buyer/seller...') {
       $('.new_inquiry form .messages .conflict').show();
     }
});
```

When is triggered `$('.new_inquiry form .messages .conflict').show();` if there is opened other div I want hide it if class is different of `.conflict`

Comment: Multiple ways, [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/), [is(:visible)](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Comment: what do you want? to hide other div at same level.

Comment: Yeahh all divs at same level. In this case `account` div must be hiden when is triggered `$('.new_inquiry form .messages .conflict').show();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to show the .conflict div and hide others when this shows.

to do this you can use `.siblings()` function of jquery.

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SVQaW/
although it just a dummy scenario try using your way.

```
$('#inquiry_theme').change(function(){
    if($('#inquiry_theme').val() == 'Conflict with the buyer/seller...') {
       $('.new_inquiry form .messages .conflict').show();
       $('.new_inquiry form .messages .conflict').siblings().hide();
     }
});
```